# inability to compile fortran 90 codes

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using a bash shell on my Mac OS X. I have fortran95 compiler installed in `/sw/bin/gfortran`. every time I attempt to access the compiler, I receive 
the error:

> "Segmentation fault: 11".  I cannot call any programs the regular way
>   i.e. "gfortran program.f90 -o executable_name "

I am not sure about the problem. Even simple programs which `print "hello world"` to screen will not work.

Comment: How did you install the thing? Where did you get it? This question might be better suited to a different site, like the superuser.stackexchange or unix stackexchange.

Comment: sounds like a reinstall is needed

Comment: Are you running from a terminal window or using some other technique

Answer (score 0):

May be a problem with your installation as already mentioned.  A couple things I would try:

1. Make sure the shared libraries it is compiled against are being found:

   otool -L /sw/bin/gfortran
2. Compile with some switches that might give you more helpful info.  I found using the backtrace option really helps especially to debug seg. faults.  You might try to compile with some options such as:

   gfortran -g -fbounds-check -Wall -fbacktrace program.f90